# Optimize run time of delete SQL Query multiple combination of data

Tags: c#, sql, sql-delete

I am using a local Access database and remote SQL Server Database

I always save results on my local database and then then the local machine is not in use I transfer this data to the remote server and clear the local data

The queries of the copy of the data to the server are running fine.

for 3000 rows of data, its take 100MS and less and it's fine
But when I try to delete the data from the local machine Its take about 3 seconds

And the data maybe can be about 20K rows of data then it can take really a lot of time...

the Datatable table it's the rows that I want to delete by ReportNumber and NumberInTest of the report

for example, I have report 1 and the number of data in the report 1,2,3,4,5,6... 
report 2 and data in the report 1,2,3,4,5,6...

The number of tests can get to 20K or even more

I assumes that in the total table will not get more than 50K In one run

ther is any way to optimize my query?

This is my delete SQL method:

```
public void ClearLocalResult(OleDbConnection openCon, DataTable table)
        {
            try
            {
                Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

                for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    try
                    {

                        string query = $"DELETE FROM [Result] where [ReportNumber]=@NumberInTest AND [NumberInTest]=@ReportNumber";

                        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, openCon);

                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue($"@ReportNumber", table.Rows[i]["ReportNumber"].ToString());
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue($"@NumberInTest", table.Rows[i]["NumberInTest"].ToString());

                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        LocalPulserDBManagerInstance.WriteLog(ex.StackTrace, ex.Message);
                        throw ex;
                    }
                }
                stopwatch.Stop();
                long time = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                LocalPulserDBManagerInstance.WriteLog(ex.StackTrace, ex.Message);
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

Comment: In general, `DELETE` statements in SQL are very expensive. I'm not sure about MS Access specific implementations, but I wouldn't be surprised if that was the case there as well. I would optimize your architecture instead of trying to speed up deletes. Why are you syncing an Access DB to a remote SQL Server instead of using it directly?

Comment: Because can be a network problem and I don't want to stop the work when the network is off...

Comment: There likely isn't an easy solution. The only thing your code is doing is deleting rows, and as with other RDBMS, it's taking a while. There's really nothing to optimize. Inserts and updates in general are faster; you could keep track of which rows have been copied and not show them to users, basically a logical or soft delete. Then, some time when the system is not busy (at night), perform the delete statement on anything that has been logically deleted. But again, that adds coding overhead.

Comment: I thought to my self, maybe there is any way to union this query to one query or less than 50K for 50K rows.  
What do you think?

Or maybe change the query by using the form instead of where for the condition it is possible? it makes sense to think that it can be faster?